# Knapsack variation NP-complete

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computational-mathematics, discrete-optimization

I have *C* processors and $C$ items that have to be run on it. I can either run each item on a seperate processor and have a running time of $\sum_{i=1}^{c} c_i$, or divide the $C$ items into $k$ subsets of size $s_i$, $i = 1,\dots, k$, $\sum s_i = C$, and run each subset on $s_i$ processors with a running time associated with the subset. If we pick a subset the order is determined, so each subset is only associated with 1 running time costs.

I see in this problem a set partition problem with an objective function, or a special case of the knapsack problem, but I can't figure out whether this problem in NP-hard and if it is, which approximation algorithms I might use. Any help would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are $2^C$ subsets, your input size is $2^C$. Meanwhile your search space is a partition into subsets, which has complexity of roughly ${(0.792C / \log C)}^C$ (see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_numbers#Growth_rate). In terms of the growth rate $Y$ of search space vs. input size $X$, you get the relationship $Y = X^{O({\log C})}$. Problems with that kind of complexity relationship between inputs and search space size are often generally believed to be NP-hard if no polynomial time solution can be found, but are notoriously hard to actually prove to be NP-hard because the search space size vs. input size for known NP-hard problems is generally pure exponential or worse, rather than having a double-logarithmic exponent. ($\log_2 C = \log_2 \log_2 2^C$, where $2^C$ is the input size).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be seen as a 0/1 integer linear programming problem which is closely related to knapsack. You have $2^C - 1$ costs $w_S$ associated with each non-empty subset $S$.  Then you similarly have $2^C -1$ indicator variables $x_S$ which are 1 if subset $S$ is included in your partition, otherwise 0. You want to minimize $\sum_S w_S x_S$. The constraints are that all $x_S$ are either 0 or 1, and also for each element $m = 1, 2, \ldots, C$, the sum of $x_S$ for all subsets $S$ that contain $m$ must be equal to 1. This gives you a 0/1 integer linear program with $2^C - 1$ variables and $C$ constraints. The total search space size is roughly $(0.792C / \log C)^C$ so I'm not sure if solving the 0/1 integer linear program will be faster than brute force, but there has been a lot of research into speeding up 0/1 integer linear programming solvers and you only have $C$ constraints so it may be worth a try. For an approximation, you can use linear programming relaxation by removing the integer constraints and then just greedily choose the subset with the highest value of $x_S$ and then remove elements in $S$ from consideration and then similarly choose the next subset from the remaining elements, etc. (Non-integer) linear programming solvers such as the simplex method often run very very fast in practice.